# A VNC solution that supports multiple screens

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote, remote-access

I am using Windows with two screens, and I have to connect to another linux box to work. I am looking for a solution in which I can:

1. display my Linux desktop in both of my screens.
2. I can drag windows between two screens (of Linux Desktop) as if I were doing that on Windows.
3. If I click "maximize" on one window, it maximizes to the screen it is in, not the whole two screens.

RealVNC can support (1) and (2) pretty nicely, but not not (3). :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/). It's not VNC, but it may suit your needs. I use it on my Windows machines. Xming starts an X server on your windows machine, then you can forward any X windows to your Windows machine.